# searching by all fields with like in 2 tables left join - performance issues?

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

i am doing left join between 2 tables in firebird sql 2.5, and i need to search them as strings with like statement.

it is like :

> Table: USER :
>
> ID | NAME | TIME | ADDRESS_FK

.

> Table : ADDRESS:
>
> ID | STREET | CITY | COUNTRY

I would like after joining theese 2 tables, to perform search for a matching string on each of the result fields.

- what is the best performance way to do it, or this is the only one possible ?

Comment: Search them how?  What is your schema design like, and what have you tried so far?  What is your sample data and results?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please ask freely if i need to add something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example Queries

#### Country Only

```
SELECT *
FROM "USER"
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON ("USER".ADDRESS_FK = ADDRESS.ID)
WHERE ADDRESS.COUNTRY LIKE 'TURKEY'
```

#### Country and City

```
SELECT *
FROM "USER"
LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON ("USER".ADDRESS_FK = ADDRESS.ID)
WHERE ADDRESS.COUNTRY LIKE 'TURKEY' AND ADDRESS.CITY LIKE 'ISTANBUL'
```

Comment: No need to use `LIKE` if no wildcard is specified

Comment: it was just an example data,probably queries will be wildcarded

Comment: I see... Seems like there is not other option :| Thank you very much guys ! You are greath ! :)